# How to display AWS s3 image on laravel 5.7 blade

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-s3

Please am absolutely new to laravel and I'm learning how to upload image to Amazon s3 which am done with that....but the problem is how to show the image in my laravel blade....

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem...

$imagePath = request()->file('image'); 
$setImageName = time().'.'.$imagePath->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filePath = 'upload/'.$setImageName;  //please note that 'upload' will be created at AWS s3, inside your bucket. 
$storage = Storage::disk('s3');
$storage->input($filePath,  fopen($imagePath,  'r+'), 'public');

//please note,  before your use Storage ::disk('s3); you must call it in your controller.

How to save the path to your database...

$posts->image = $filePath; 
$posts->save();

How to display in your view....

url($post->image)  }}" >

//Note you must loop through for you to get $post.

HOPE IT HELPS.....